# Select latest row for each group from oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with user comments in a guestbook. Columns are: id, user_id, title, comment, timestamp.

I need to select the latest row for each user. 
I have tried to do this with group by but havent managed it because i cant select anything else in the same query where i group by user_id:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(ts) FROM comments GROUP BY user_id
```

for example in this query i cant add to also select columns id, tilte and comment. How can this be done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use analytic functions

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT c.*,
               rank() over (partition by user_id order by ts desc) rnk
          FROM comments c)
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

Depending on how you want to handle ties (if there can be two rows with the same `user_id` and `ts`), you may want to use the `row_number` or `dense_rank` function rather than `rank`.  `rank` would allow multiple rows to be first if there was a tie.  `row_number` would arbitrarily return one row if there was a tie.  `dense_rank` would behave like `rank` for the rows that tied for first but would consider the next row to be second rather than third assuming two rows tie for first.

Answer (score 11):

You can build on your query using a `JOIN`:

```
select c.*
from comments c join
     (select user_id, max(ts) as maxts
      from comments c2
      group by user_id
     ) cc
     on c.user_id = cc.user_id and c.ts = cc.maxts;
```

There are other ways.  Typical advice is to use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select c.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by ts desc) as seqnum
      from comments c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

These two queries are subtly different.  The first will return duplicates if the most recent comment for a user had exactly the same `ts`.  The second returns one row per user.

Answer (score 4):

This type of problems has a very simple and very efficient solution with the `dense rank first/last` function:

```
select id,
       max(user_id) keep (dense_rank last order by ts) over (partition by id) as user_id,
       max(title)   keep (dense_rank last order by ts) over (partition by id) as title,
       max(comment) keep (dense_rank last order by ts) over (partition by id) as comment,
       max(ts)                                                                as ts
from   comments;
```